# dd writing on USB flash drive causes massive reads

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, dd

I am currently restoring a usb stick with a dd image, I have previously created. However is noticed very poor write speed around ~7 MB/s although the stick is usually much faster.

After looking around a little, I noticed that a lot of data is being read from the USB drive which explains the poor write performance. Nothing but dd is accessing the device at that time.

Edited `atop` line:

```
sdd: busy 101% | read 18020 | write 613 | MBr/s 7.04 | MBw/s 7.1
```

I noticed a similar behavior when writing directly to my md array using dd. However when writing to a mounted filesystem with dd, this does not happen.

So my question is why is read from the usb stick when writing directly to the block device and whether this can be prevented to improve write performance?

Comment: What specific `dd` command switches are you running?  And what variety of file systems are you running/writing?

Comment: @ice13berg I used ``dd if=/dev/sdX > lbzip2 image-dd.bz2`` to create the image and am now using ``lbzcat image-dd.bz2 | dd of=/deb/sdX`` to restore it.

Comment: Regarding the md array: RAID 5 or RAID 6? If so, are you using the stripe size as dd blocksize?

Comment: @Hennes It's a RAID-6 and in the case of RAID i do expect some read activity when writing due to parity calculation but less than I have seen. I did not set any blocksize for the dd command on the RAID array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, not 100% clear what might be happening, but my suspicion is that you're writing small blocks (512-byte) to the USB, and then dd checks to make sure the byte is written properly - leading to LOTS of reading and writing, and reading and writing.

Tuning your block size to the "right" size isn't trivial, but there are a handfuls of rules of thumb on how to do it.  In general, I've found a 64kB block size to be a good compromise on most fronts - but your file systems can drive changes to that, if you're running anything exotic (like `zfs`, for example).

Try something like this:
`lbzcat image-dd.bz2 | dd of=/deb/sdX bs=64k`

For a more lengthy discussion, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161823/dd-how-to-calculate-optimal-blocksize).

Comment: Am I then correct in the assumption that, when dd'ing to a file on a filesystm, the blocksize set with dd does not matter, because the fs handles the "real" writes to the block device and has (hopefully) been setup with correct block sizes?

Comment: You're definitely getting outside my lane with that question, but I think the answer is "no."  I believe you'll find that if you know the file system you're writing TO, and you know the file system you're writing FROM, there is some optimal block size (or sizes) to use in `dd` to maximize both reading and writing complete blocks of data - optimizing the data check `dd` does, and minimizing the amount of incomplete written blocks.  For example, I don't think using the fs would be able to help `bs=3bytes` or `bs=61bytes`.

Answer (score 2):

For me, `dd` uses the page cache by default. I think this is normal on systems with page cache. Page cache needs the storage device to be read though, which can cause slow write speed.

For me there are 3 ways of getting around this and getting full speed:

1. Set `dd` block size to 4096 or a multiple. (no reads)
2. Set `dd` block size to a sufficiently large number. For me this was about 1 million and above. I got full speed at about 1 million. (very few reads)
3. Don't use page cache by giving `dd` parameter `oflags=direct`. Set `dd` block size to a sufficiently large multiple of 512. For me this was about `bs=120k` and above. (no reads)

Something to note, on my system **block size** for all storage devices and **page size** are 4096 bytes. Found with:

```
blockdev --getbsz /dev/sd?
getconf PAGESIZE
```

Also **sector size** is 512 bytes.
`fdisk` and maybe `parted` can tell you sector size.